# Meaning of "Whats your damage" and tense in 'was taken up the whole sidewalk'

Tags: phrase-meaning, slang, spoken-english

> Girl 1 - Whats your damage?
>
> Girl 2 - Oh! I'm sorry, its just your fat ass was taken up the whole
>   sidewalk.

This is the conversation of two girls when the Girl 1 pushed Girl 2 for some reason.

Now, my first question is - What does *"whats your damage"* means and when do we exactly use this expression or dialogue?

And my second question is - Why did the Girl 2 said *"your fat ass was taken up the whole.."* instead of *"your fat ass had taken up the whole"* and please explain me deeply so that I could use these things (things = dialogue and grammar rule) correctly in my conversation.

Comment: As for question 2, people who are wont to say "fat ass" don't usually concern themselves too much with proper, formal grammar.

Comment: Also, are you sure Girl 2 said "...was taken up the whole sidewalk" and not, "...was **takin'** up the whole sidewalk"? The words _taken_ and _takin'_ sound quite alike, and the latter – as a shortened form of _taking_ – would be grammatically correct.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect Girl 2 said *"your fat ass was **taking** up the whole sidewalk."*  In casual conversation,  words ending in *-ing* are often pronounced as if they ended *-in* or *-en.*  (At least in the USA)

In quotations,  you will often see such words rendered with an apostrophe: *...was **takin'** up the whole..."*

As for your other question, about the meaning of *"What's your damage."*  This is highly casual American slang.  For language in that category, Urban Dictionary can be a good starting place (*) to understand slang:  "[What's your damage.](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=what%27s%20your%20damage%3F)"  Basically it is synonymous with *"What's your problem,"* but is used far less widely.

(*) Note that inclusion in Urban Dictionary does not mean that a word or term enjoys widespread usage.  Anyone can add anything to Urban Dictionary, and there are many, many entries there that I have *never* heard in the wild.  I would recommend that you use it to understand things you hear, but not as a source of slang that you wish to use yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding "What's your damage?", it implies emotional, psychological, or brain damage more strongy and specifically than "What's your problem?"

Comment: Please do not repeat other answers on SE sites

Comment: I don't believe I am repeating another answer. I am highlighting the perceived difference between "what's your problem" and "what's your damage", and if you were referring to any answers in the linked to Urban Dictionary, again, I'm not repeating any answers from there, but may have incidentally summarized what a couple of them imply.

Answer (score 0):

**"What’s your damage"** is just another way of asking “what’s wrong with you”.
I wouldn’t equate it with **"what’s your problem"** as that suggests the inquiry is about a person’s issue with an external situation(What’s your problem with me/the situation etc).

"What’s your damage" is more so inquiring about an issue with the person’s mental or emotional state.
“What is your damage” (is it mental, physical, emotional etc.) naturally, this question is rhetorical.

The modern slang equivalent would be something along the line of “**Are you well(in the head)**?”.